# Why is jqueryval bundle rendering empty?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

I am trying to render a script bundle but it is coming up empty.

Here's the script bundle declaration in BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                  "~/jquery.unobtrusive.ajax*",
                  "~/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.bootstrap*"));
```

And in my view

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

But when I load the page, the jqueryval script comes up empty.

```
<script src="/bundles/jquery?v=Nsx6sB8o7LJCR51P5u-dfe-6LePnt87pD0P5VTJ-0wI1"></script>

<script src="/bundles/bootstrap?v=XkxfR798CUJPhMhSd0B8VYgZWSNOTtLvz6047jf84wQ1"></script>

<script src="/bundles/modernizr?v=K-FFpFNtIXPUlQamnX3qHX_A5r7TM2xbAgcuEmpm3O41"></script>

<script src="/bundles/jqueryval?v="></script>
```

The debugger in Firefox says returns a 200 status when retrieving the files for the bundle, but the filesize is 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, your paths are incorrect. This:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                  "~/jquery.unobtrusive.ajax*",
                  "~/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.bootstrap*"));
```

should be

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                  "~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive.ajax*",
                  "~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.bootstrap*"));
```

Remember, `~/` maps to the site's virtual root directory when the path is being resolved, so unless you're placing JavaScript files in the site root, those paths in your bundle will not work.

Comment: Ugh. Hiding in plain sight. Thanks.